# Как сделать бекграунд таблицы на всю ширину?

Tags: css, flexbox

Подскажите, как сделать бекграунд на всю ширину таблицы?
А сейчас есть гор-й скролл, и если проскролить, то та часть, которая была изначально скрыта, не закрашена
https://jsfiddle.net/1dvbsLLu/4/

```js
$('.icon').on('click', function(e){
 $('.row__content').slideToggle(500);
})
```

```css
ul{
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
}
.table{
   width: 900px; 
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row-grid{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.row__top{
  background: gray;
}
.row__content{
  display: none;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
}
.icon{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cell{
  width: 30%;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row__top row-grid">
          <div class="cell"><i class="icon"></i></div>
          <div class="cell">2</div>
          <div class="cell">3</div>
          <div class="cell">4</div>
          <div class="cell">5</div>
          <div class="cell">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row__content row-grid">
          <div class="cell">content</div>
          <div class="cell">content2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: задать background: gray; для .table

Comment: @soledar10, да, это верно, но один нюанс, извиняюсь, что сразу это не указал в вопросе, нужно чтобы background: gray был для блока, который открывается в аккордеоне, т.е. для блока row__content.  чтобы при открытии бэкграунд нижнего блока был на всю ширину. https://jsfiddle.net/1dvbsLLu/5/

Comment: это немного посложней

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1dvbsLLu/6/